# JAXB XML Object Marshalling without any namespace prefixes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

Yes, I already found this [JAXB XML Object Marshalling without namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586304/jaxb-xml-object-marshalling-without-namespace-prefixes)...

But my problem is that I have different namespaces in my xml so what jaxb produces is:

```
<Root xmlns="http://A" xmlns:ns1="http://B">
    <A>
       <A1 />
    </A>
    <ns1:B>
       <ns1:B1 />
    </ns1:B>
</Root>
```

but what I need is

```
<Root xmlns="http://A">
    <A>
       <A1 />
    </A>
    <B xmlns="http://B">
       <B1 />
    </B>
 </Root>
```

How is it possible to archive this?