# Create Element with atom as prefix using JAXB annotations

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb

I'm trying to create an xml element which i want to have as prefix the atom.
I know that i can't do this:

```
@XmlElement(prefix="atom")
```

And create

```
<XmlAttribute>
   <atom:link ...>
</XmlAttribute>
```

Is there a possible way to do this or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to define the namespace corresponding to this prefix:

```
@XmlElement(name="link", namespace="..")
```

this will just add the namespace corresponding to the `atom` prefix to your `link` element. If your question is about specifically getting `atom` as the prefix for this namespace, then please look at this question: [Is it possible to customize the namespace prefix that JAXB uses when marshalling to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982977/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-namespace-prefix-that-jaxb-uses-when-marshalling)