# @XmlAttribute(name) invalid name in SoapUI

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, soapui

I am making SOAP web services and when I use

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "asd:resource")
private String asdResource;
```

I can not import my wsdl in SoapUI. It shows:
Error: The value 'asd:resource' is an invalid name.

And when I use only `@XmlAttribute` I can import my project but in the response I am receiving it like asdResource without :.
That is why I used `XmlAttribute(name= "asd:resource")`

My question is what can cause this problem and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this class.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "yournamespace", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns = {
    @XmlNs(prefix="asd", namespaceURI="yournamespace"),
})


package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

And for

```
@XmlAttribute(namespace = "yournamespace")
private String resource;
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparenty you want to create an attribute with the name `resource` in a specific namespace. This should be:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "resource", namespace="http://...")
```

`namespace` should be the namespace associated with the prefix `asd`.

When marshalling, JAXB will typically "invent" its own namespace prefixes (like `ns0` etc.). See the following question if you want to control namespace prefixes:

> [Is it possible to customize the namespace prefix that JAXB uses when marshalling to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982977/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-namespace-prefix-that-jaxb-uses-when-marshalling)

Comment: I fixed this with package-info:
 @XmlNs(prefix="asd", namespaceURI="uri),